# Including Q_OBJECT macro causes compiler errors when using VS add-in

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt

I am using the Visual Studio add-in to try to create a QT project in Visual Studio.  When I create a new class that uses the `Q_OBJECT` macro, I get compiler errors.  Removing the macro makes the errors disappear.  Here is an example header file.

```
#ifndef TELEVISION_H
#define TELEVISION_H

#include <QObject>
#include <Qt\qwidget.h>
#include <Qt\qpainter.h>

class Television : public QWidget
{
    //Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Television(QWidget *parent = 0);
}

#endif
```

Uncommenting and re-commenting the `Q_OBJECT` line makes the compiler errors come and go.  The errors are all in `moc_television.cpp` (the auto-generated cpp file).  The errors don't seem helpful, for example:

> 1>GeneratedFiles\Debug\moc_Television.cpp(20): error C2146: syntax
>   error : missing ';' before identifier 'qt_meta_data_Television'

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a semicolon at the end of your class `Television` definition.

Comment: This seems to happen way too often.. Thanks

Comment: this answer helped me so much. got similar issue but with "error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body" on one of my mocfiles. was missing a "};" in the end of the file...